# Find KNN with a geometry data type using POSTGIS in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgis, knn

i want to find k nearest points for a point with the best performance in postgresql using PostGIS.

The structure of my table is :

`CREATE TABLE mylocations 
    (id integer, 
    name varchar, 
    geom geometry);`

sample inserted row is:

`INSERT INTO mylocations VALUES
  (5, 'Alaska', 'POINT(-172.7078 52.373)');`

I can find nearest points by ST_Distance() with the following query :

`SELECT ST_Distance(geography(geom), 'POINT(178.1375 51.6186)'::geometry) as distance,ST_AsText(geom),name, id
FROM mylocations
ORDER BY distance limit 10;`

but actually i want to find them without calculating distance of my points with all points of table.
in fact i want to find the best query with best performance, because my table would have huge data.
i appreciate for your thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `<->` operator which `Returns the 2D distance between A and B`. Make sure your `geom` types and `SRID` are the same.

```
SELECT ST_Distance(geom, 
       'POINT(178.1375 51.6186)'::geometry) as distance,
       ST_AsText(geom),
       name, id
FROM mylocations
ORDER BY geom <-> 'POINT(178.1375 51.6186)'::geometry limit 10
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but when i use this query i feel my result is not correct.
i don`t know how to find nearest points to one point.
indeed i have not added SRID to all points in the table yet.
because every point have different SRID than others. 

my query is :

```
SELECT id, name, st_astext(geom) from mylocations where st_dwithin(geom, st_geomfromtext('POINT(-149.3783 56.53)'), 20000)
```

i think 20000 is based on meter. right?

Comment: @Mahsa Have you indexed your geom column?  If not, try running `CREATE INDEX mylocations_points_gix ON mylocations USING GIST (geom);` before the above query.

Comment: For your question, it gives you distance in meters for `geography` types.  Since your points are of `geometry` type, 20000 is `srid distance` (you can can convert both points to geography via casting `::geography` if you really want to do the manual distance calculatoin).

Answer (score 1):

finally i could answer to my question with this query:

```
SELECT id, name 
FROM mylocations 
WHERE ST_DWithin(geom::geography,
                 ST_GeogFromText('POINT(-73.856077 40.848447)'),
                 1609, false);
```

actually i want to give a point as a center of a circle with radius 1609 (as meter) and get all neighbours have distance less than 1609 meter to center of the circle.